# Change URL of products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, permalinks

My WooCommerce products link are like this:

```
http://domine.com/product/sample-product/
```

I want to change them to:

```
http://domin.com/product-catagorys/prodactname
```

I tried permalink option in setting but failed.
how can I do that?

Comment: What did you try exactly? Because the permalinks settings are the answer for changing the permalink structure.

Comment: Add this plugin 

https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

> Login to admin panel and Go to the **`Dashboard`** > **`Settings`** > **`Permalinks`**
>   and under **`Product Permalinks`** section there is an option called *Custom
>   Base* set it to `/%product_cat%`

[image]

Hope this helps!